# Simple Weka classification example in Java gives inconsistent answers

Tags: decision-trees, java, weka

I have the following simple weka code to use a simple decision tree, train it, and then make predictions.

```
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import weka.classifiers.Classifier;
import weka.classifiers.trees.SimpleCart;
import weka.core.Instances;
import weka.core.converters.ConverterUtils;

public class weka_test {

    public static String labelFeature = "LABEL";

    public Instances readData(String file) throws Exception {
        ConverterUtils.DataSource source = new ConverterUtils.DataSource(file);
        return source.getDataSet();
    }

    public double accuracy(Classifier myClass, Instances testData) {
        float correctPreds = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < testData.numInstances(); i++){
            String actual = testData.instance(i).stringValue(testData.classAttribute());

            String label = null;
            try {
                double pred = myClass.classifyInstance(testData.instance(i));
                label = testData.classAttribute().value((int) pred);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(CategorizationTrain.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

            if (label.equals(actual)) {
                correctPreds++;
            }
        }       
        return correctPreds / testData.numInstances();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        CategorizationTrain t = new CategorizationTrain();

        Instances data = null;
        data = t.readData("train.csv");

        if (data == null) {
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        else {
             System.out.println("data was read and the size is: " + data.numAttributes() + "x" + data.numInstances());
        }

        // Set label
        data.setClass(data.attribute(labelFeature));

        System.out.println("label: " + data.classAttribute().name() + " --- index: " + data.classIndex());


        // Try SimpleCart decision tree/classifier
        SimpleCart tree = new SimpleCart(); 

        tree.buildClassifier(data);

        double acc = t.accuracy(tree, data);
        System.out.println("Accuracy = " + acc);  


        System.out.println("tree(SimpleCart): " + tree);    
        weka.core.SerializationHelper.write("tree.model", tree);

        SimpleCart newTree = null;
        newTree = (SimpleCart) weka.core.SerializationHelper.read("tree.model");

        acc = t.accuracy(newTree, data);
        System.out.println("Accuracy = " + acc);         

        Instances test = null;

        test = t.readData("test.csv");        
        test.setClass(test.attribute(labelFeature));        
        System.out.println(test.attribute(labelFeature));

        double newPred = -1.0;
        for (int i=0; i<test.numInstances(); i++) {
            newPred = newTree.classifyInstance(test.instance(i));
            System.out.println(test.instance(i));
            String label = data.classAttribute().value((int) newPred);
            System.out.println("Index: " + newPred + " Prediction = " + label);  
            newPred = -1.0;
        }
        System.out.println("-----------------------------");
        for (int i=0; i<data.numInstances(); i++) {
            newPred = newTree.classifyInstance(data.instance(i));
            System.out.println(data.instance(i));
            String label = data.classAttribute().value((int) newPred);
            System.out.println("Index: " + newPred + " Prediction = " + label);  
            newPred = -1.0;
        }
    }
}
```

My train data is just:

```
VALUE   LABEL   KEYWORD
300     x28x    John
-71.46  x1x     Mary
-22     x28x    John
-2207.99    x26x    Mary
193.33  x28x    John
12200   x28x    Mary
-16     x7x     James
-1.29   x7x     James
-120    x1x     Mary
-6.7    x28x    John
```

and my test data is the same without the "label":

```
VALUE   LABEL   KEYWORD
300             John
-71.46          Mary
-22             John
-2207.99        Mary
193.33          John
12200           Mary
-16             James
-1.29           James
-120            Mary
-6.7            John
```

Since test and train are the same, I was expecting the same predictions, but I have different results. What am I doing wrong?

Predictions on test:

```
300,?,John
Index: 1.0 Prediction = x1x
-71.46,?,Mary
Index: 0.0 Prediction = x28x
-22,?,John
Index: 1.0 Prediction = x1x
-2207.99,?,Mary
Index: 0.0 Prediction = x28x
193.33,?,John
Index: 1.0 Prediction = x1x
12200,?,Mary
Index: 1.0 Prediction = x1x
-16,?,James
Index: 0.0 Prediction = x28x
-1.29,?,James
Index: 0.0 Prediction = x28x
-120,?,Mary
Index: 0.0 Prediction = x28x
-6.7,?,John
Index: 1.0 Prediction = x1x
```

Predictions on train:

```
300,x28x,John
Index: 0.0 Prediction = x28x
-71.46,x1x,Mary
Index: 1.0 Prediction = x1x
-22,x28x,John
Index: 0.0 Prediction = x28x
-2207.99,x26x,Mary
Index: 1.0 Prediction = x1x
193.33,x28x,John
Index: 0.0 Prediction = x28x
12200,x28x,Mary
Index: 0.0 Prediction = x28x
-16,x7x,James
Index: 3.0 Prediction = x7x
-1.29,x7x,James
Index: 3.0 Prediction = x7x
-120,x1x,Mary
Index: 1.0 Prediction = x1x
-6.7,x28x,John
Index: 0.0 Prediction = x28x
```

Answer (score 0):

Just because you trained the model on a dataset, it does not mean it will have 100% accuracy in predicting on it. I ran a similar test today on another dataset I was working with and only got 90% accuracy when I ran the model on training data.

100% is actually really uncommon and usually means you are overfitting. Try showing the confusion matrix for your training run and see how much Weka claimed it got right.

Comment: That is not at all what I am asking, you did not even read the question, I know that. The prediction can be wrong but it needs to be consistent, it cannot make a prediction once, and then, on the same item, a different prediction.

Comment: Did you inspect the tree?